# Tabela não exibe dados

Tags: java, jsp

A tabela não exibe os dados, mas estou a 4 horas revisando e não acho nada que esteja incorreto

```
package dao;

import Connection.Conexao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import model.Paises;

/**
 *
 * @author pedro
 */
public class AmericaSulDao {
    
    private Connection connection;

    public AmericaSulDao() {
        connection = Conexao.getConnection();
    }
    
        public void addPaises(Paises americaSul) {
        Connection con = Conexao.getConnection();
        
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        try {
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO paises (nome_pais, continente_id_continente, id_paises)VALUES(?,?,?)");
            stmt.setString(1, americaSul.getNomePais());
            stmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        }
        
        public void deleteAmericaSul(int IdAmericaSul) {
        String            sqlString = "update continente set nome_pais=?, continente_id_continente=?, id_paises=? where cd_paises=?";
        PreparedStatement stm       = null;
        
        try {
            stm = connection.prepareStatement("delete from  where id_paises=?");
            // Parameters start with 1
            stm.setInt(1, IdAmericaSul);  
            stm.executeUpdate();
            stm.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
        public void updateAmericaSul(Paises americaSul) {
        
        PreparedStatement stm       = null;
        
        try {
            stm = connection.prepareStatement("update continente set nome_pais=?, continente_id_continente=?, id_paises=? where cd_paises=?");
            
            stm.setString(1, americaSul.getNomePais());
            stm.setInt(2, americaSul.getContinente_id_continente());
            stm.setInt(3, americaSul.getIdPaises());  
            stm.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
        public List<Paises> getAllAmericaSul() {
        List<Paises> listaAmericaSul = new ArrayList<Paises>();
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = America do Sul");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Paises americaSul = new Paises();  
                americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nome_pais"));
                americaSul.setIdContinente(rs.getInt("continente_id_continente"));
                americaSul.setIdPaises(rs.getInt("id_paises"));
                listaAmericaSul.add(americaSul);
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listaAmericaSul;
    }

    public Paises getAmericaSulByID(int idAmericaSul) {
        Paises americaSul = new Paises();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = America do Sul and id_paises=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, idAmericaSul);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                americaSul.setIdContinente(rs.getInt("continente_id_continente"));
                americaSul.setIdPaises(rs.getInt("id_paises"));
                americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nm_paises"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return americaSul;
    }
    
}
```

Arquivo DAO

```
package controller;

import dao.AmericaSulDao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.Continentes;
import model.Paises;

/**
 *
 * @author pedro
 */
@WebServlet(name = "AmericaSul", urlPatterns = {"/AmericaSulController"})
public class AmericaSulController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/telaAmericaSul.jsp";
    private static String LIST_CONT = "/telaAmericaSul.jsp";
    private AmericaSulDao dao;

    public AmericaSulController() {
        super();
        dao = new AmericaSulDao();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward="";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
            int IdAmericaSul = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul"));
            dao.deleteAmericaSul(IdAmericaSul);
            forward = LIST_CONT;
            request.setAttribute("americaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul()); 
        } 
        
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            int IdAmericaSul = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul"));
            Paises americaSul = dao.getAmericaSulByID(IdAmericaSul);
            request.setAttribute("americaSul", americaSul);     
        } 
        
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listaAmericaSul")){
            forward = LIST_CONT;
            request.setAttribute("americaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul());
        }
        
        else {
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Paises americaSul = new Paises();
        americaSul.setIdContinente(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_paises")));
        americaSul.setNomePais(request.getParameter("nome_pais"));
        americaSul.setIdContinente(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("continente_id_continente")));

        String IdAmericaSul = request.getParameter("IdAmericaSul");
        if(IdAmericaSul == null || IdAmericaSul.isEmpty())
        {
            dao.addPaises(americaSul);
        }
        else
        {
            americaSul.setIdPaises(Integer.parseInt(IdAmericaSul));
            dao.updateAmericaSul(americaSul);
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_CONT);
        request.setAttribute("IdAmericaSul", dao.getAllAmericaSul());
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os erros estão nos códigos em que está fazendo `nome_continente = America do Sul`.

> ```
> public List<Paises> getAllAmericaSul() {
>         List<Paises> listaAmericaSul = new ArrayList<Paises>();
>         try {
>             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
>             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = America do Sul");
>             while (rs.next()) {
>                 Paises americaSul = new Paises();  
>                 americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nome_pais"));
>                 americaSul.setIdContinente(rs.getInt("continente_id_continente"));
>                 americaSul.setIdPaises(rs.getInt("id_paises"));
>                 listaAmericaSul.add(americaSul);
>                 
>             }
>         } catch (SQLException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         return listaAmericaSul;
>     }
> ```

Observe esta linha:

> ```
> ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = America do Sul");
> ```

### Corrija para:

```
public List<Paises> getAllAmericaSul() {
        List<Paises> listaAmericaSul = new ArrayList<Paises>();
        String clausulaProcura = "select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = ?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(clausulaProcura);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "America do Sul");
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Paises americaSul = new Paises();  
                americaSul.setNomePais(rs.getString("nome_pais"));
                americaSul.setIdContinente(rs.getInt("continente_id_continente"));
                americaSul.setIdPaises(rs.getInt("id_paises"));
                listaAmericaSul.add(americaSul);
                
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaAmericaSul;
}
```

Corrija seu `select` fazendo as junções das tabelas adequadamente conforme sua estrutura das tabelas utilizando `left join` ou `inner join`. Sugiro que antes de colocar a consulta no código, teste antes em uma ferramenta adequada de consulta *SQL*.

Corrija também o método `getAmericaSulByID(int idAmericaSul)`, visto que possui erro semelhante.

Observe a linha abaixa e faça a correção necessária:

> ```
> PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = America do Sul and id_paises=?");
> ```

Comment: Mesmo eu fazendo o inner join e corrigindo o código o erro persiste, existe algo além disso que possa estar causando problema?

Comment: No método `getAllAmericaSul()` está gerando algum erro? Ou no final do procedimento está a variável `listaAmericaSul` está vazia? No `select` está `select nome_pais from paises, continente where nome_continente = ?`, então só está selecionando o campo `nome_pais` e está tentando acessar outros campos como `continente_id_continente` e `id_paises`. Se pretende acessar, precisa incluir tais campos no seu `select`.

Comment: Seguiu minha sugestão: *"Sugiro que antes de colocar a consulta no código, teste antes em uma ferramenta adequada de consulta SQL."*. Há ferramentas como o DBeaver que você pode conectar a vários tipos de banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui arrumar, estava passando um parâmetro errado na hora de receber os dados.

Comment: Ótimo @PedroViniciusSantosRodrigue, que bom que ajudei. Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) .